# Margin div through nested while loop

Tags: php, css, loops, html

I have a loop within a loop (PHP) like this:

```
while(mysql...) {
 echo $row1->name.'<img src="info.png" />';
 while(another_mysql...) {
  echo $row2->name.'<img src="image.png" />';
 }
}
```

now this will result something like this:

```
head_1 [info.png]
value_a1 [image.png]
value_a2 [image.png]
value_a3 [image.png]
head_2 [info.png]
value_b1 [image.png]
value_b2 [image.png]
```

as you can see, the images are not in a straight line because the values can be different causing the images to be pushed further right.

when converting the value using `str_pad();` it does work but not stable and bugs a little.
i don't know how to put the images in a div right next to the div the values are in because the loops will not like it.

what can i do to have it output something like:

```
head1      [info.png]
value_a1   [image.png]
value_a2   [image.png]
value_a3   [image.png]
head2      [info.png]
value_b1   [image.png]
value_b2   [image.png]
```

Comment: You must first know the max length of the names so you can pad the names to that length + 3 when echo'ing. This means that, unless you know the max width, you must first loop through all the names before echo'ing.

Comment: @Mr.Alien You're talking about coding standard and code readability, and I fully agree with these principles, but MrMadMan wants a formatted/styled output. So MrMadMan, use CSS, take a look at Gaurav Vashishtha answer.

Comment: @JBRTRND Oh I got it, I'll remove my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to make it proper align:

```
echo "<div style='width:310px'>";
while(mysql...) {
 echo '<div style="width:50px;float:left">'.$row1->name.'</div><div style="width:250px;float:right"><img src="info.png" /></div>';
 while(another_mysql...) {
  echo '<div style="width:50px;float:left">'.$row2->name.'</div><div style="width:250px;float:right"><img src="image.png" /></div>';
 }
}
echo "</div>";
```

Use it in your while loop. hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: style="50px". You forgot the selector.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One straight-forward solution is to use tables. Something like:

```
echo '<table>'
while(mysql...) {
 echo '<tr><td>'.$row1->name.'</td><td><img src="info.png" /></td></tr>';
 while(another_mysql...) {
  echo '<tr><td>'.$row2->name.'</td><td><img src="image.png" /></td></tr>';
 }
}
echo '</table>'
```

This lets the browser take care of determining the correct widths. Other ways are using `div`s. They can be given fixed widths -- emulating a table -- or you could align the right div which contains the image using `position: absolute; right: 0;` (plus some more CSS) which would right-align all the images.